# How to resolve the "cannot read property 'contains' of undefined" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am following a tutorial and I have gotten to a point where, when I click on the drop down select option, i get the `Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined` and the `Cannot read property 'display' of undefined`. I have been trying to figure out where i might have misspelled or wrote the wrong code.  May i get some help. Below is my javascript code and my html code

**HTML - inside the body tag**

```js
// selectors
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo-button');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
const filterOption = document.querySelector('.filter-todo');

//event listeners
todoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo);
todoList.addEventListener('click', deleteCheck);
filterOption.addEventListener('click', filterTodo);

//functions

function addTodo(event) {
  console.log("hello");

  // prevent form from submitting by using code in immediate line below
  event.preventDefault();
  // todo div
  const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
  todoDiv.classList.add('todo');
  // create li
  const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
  newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
  // adding li to div
  todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
  // // check mark button
  const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
  completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>';
  completedButton.classList.add('complete-button');
  todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
  // trash button
  const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
  trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>';
  trashButton.classList.add('trash-button');
  todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);

  // append to ul
  todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
  // clear todo input value
  todoInput.value = ""
}

function deleteCheck(event) {
  const item = event.target;
  // delete
  if (item.classList[0] === 'trash-button') {
    const todo = item.parentElement;
    // animation
    todo.classList.add('fall');
    todo.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
      todo.remove();
    });
  }

  // check
  if (item.classList[0] === 'complete-button') {
    const todo = item.parentElement;
    todo.classList.toggle('completed');
  }

}

function filterTodo(event) {
  const todos = todoList.childNodes;
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    switch (event.target.value) {
      case "all":
        todo.style.display = "flex";
        break;
      case "completed":
        if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    ProfMox's To Do List
  </h1>
</header>

<form>
  <input type="text" class="todo-input">
  <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        </button>
  <div class="select">
    <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="completed">Completed</option>
      <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list">

  </ul>
</div>

<!--    <script src="./js/app.js"></script> -->
```

What exactly can I do to fix this error?

Comment: make sure classList is not undefined (childNodes includes text nodes, which do not have classList) - or `const todos = [...todoList.children];`

Comment: Not sure, but `querySelector` NodeList and not element. So they are not live elements. That might be the issue. Try fetching it again in function

Comment: @JaromandaX is there a way to work around that text element?

Comment: @ProvidenceMoyo Issue is with the type of element you are receiving in `childNode`. Its a text element. Hence the issue. Try fetching child elements as `.querySelectorAll('.todo-list li')` in your function and it works fine. [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/8o39asen/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the problem. In the html code where we have this code:

```
 <ul class="todo-list">

  </ul>
```

remove all the spaces inside the `'ul'` tag so it ends up looking like `<ul class ="todo-list"><ul>`
child nodes count those space as a text and assign an index for it.
So, if you remove everything inside the ul tag your code will run perfectly.

Also in the javascript code, add a `break` after every case.